# Polymorphism and get object type in C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, object-type

Let's say that I have 4 classes, `B,C,D,E` that inherit from `A`(abstract base class).
Also I have a container (`std::vector`) of type `A*` whose contents point to either of
`B,C,D,E` objects. 
Here are some rules:
If a `B` object and a `C` object interact, they get removed from the vector and in their place a `D` object gets created.

Also, `C + D = E`

Now, suppose that I randomly choose one of said vector contents; how would I go about knowing which object is of which type, in order to implement an interaction mechanic?

NOTE: I do not wish to use the `typeid` operator, a dynamic cast or flags. Any other solutions?

Here is some code

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
    int v;
public:
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
};

class B :public A {
public:
    B(){}
    ~B(){}
};

class C : public A {
public:
    C(){}
    ~C(){}
};

class D : public A {
public:
    D(){}
    ~D(){}
};

class E : public A {
public:
    E(){}
    ~E(){}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> container;
    return 0;
}
```

How would I implement the interact function(s) ?

Comment: Instead of describing some code, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: What is *"interact"*!? And how are the positions of the items known for you to remove them when they *"interact"*?

Comment: And regarding the "get object type", that is really not a good idea, especially in C++ for which it creates run-time overhead. Instead a design using virtual functions to handle behavior differently in different classes is usually the way to go.

Comment: If you want to know the type of an object, use `typeid(*pointer_to_object).name()`

Comment: You missed the point. *There is no action taking place in this code*.

Comment: I do not know how to implement what I am asking, that is why there is no action taking place in this code. Do I make one function? More?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do something type-specific without using anything that could identify the type. I don't think there is a solution tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use virtual functions to do the multiple dispatch

```
struct B;
struct C;
struct D;
struct E;

struct A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithA(const A&) const = 0;

//protected:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithB(const B&) const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithC(const C&) const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithD(const D&) const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithE(const E&) const = 0;
};

// Your interact rules

template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
std::unique_ptr<A> interact(const LHS&, const RHS&) { return nullptr; }

// Note that definitions and declarations must be split in reality
// to be able to compile it
std::unique_ptr<A> interact(const B&, const C&) { return std::make_unique<D>(); }
std::unique_ptr<A> interact(const C&, const D&) { return std::make_unique<E>(); }
// Maybe the reflexive case, C/B D/C ?


// The derived classes
struct B : A
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithA(const A& a) const override { return a.interactWithB(*this); }

    // Even if code look similar for other inherited class
    // the difference is in the runtime type of the objects are known.
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithB(const B& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithC(const C& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithD(const D& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithE(const E& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
};

struct C : A
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithA(const A& a) const override { return a.interactWithC(*this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithB(const B& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithC(const C& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithD(const D& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithE(const E& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
};

struct D : A
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithA(const A& a) const override { return a.interactWithD(*this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithB(const B& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithC(const C& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithD(const D& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithE(const E& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
};

struct E : A
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithA(const A& a) const override { return a.interactWithE(*this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithB(const B& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithC(const C& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithD(const D& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<A> interactWithE(const E& rhs) const override { return interact(rhs, *this); }
};
```

and then

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> v /* =  .. */;

auto a = v[i]->interactWithA(*v[j]);
if (a) {
    // Remove v[i] and v[j]
    // Insert a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds like a bad abstraction. So actually you're not solving the right problem. You should use inheritance when you don't need to know the *exact* type of the object, but instead rely on runtime polymorphism.

You can bake in some flags, like virtual function that will return an id of each type, but is rather workaround, not a solution. It is also easy to get it wrong.

```
class A
{
    ...
    virtual int get_id() = 0;
}
```

**Variants**

Instead of polymorphism, if the types are fixed (e.g. you don't plan to add or remove classes), you can use [`std::variant<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17) or boost.variant. To interact with it, you will need to use visitors and call [`std::visit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). May be it will be harder to interact with it, but, in my opinion, it will better fit as a solution for the problem you described.

Comment: Is there another way? One without the need for flags or std::variant ?

Comment: @JohnLannister, you don't give any details. I could write you "I'm eating a chocolate now, guess what chocolate I'm eating?". ABCDE don't make any sense. Nor does your description of the problem